# What is the difference between "sort of" and "a little" in spoken English？

Tags: word-difference, spoken-english

Is there any difference between the two following sentences?

> 1. I’m sort of worried about Jenny.
> 2. I’m a little worried about Jenny.

What I found is ***sort of*** is mainly used in spoken English, and ***a little*** is not. They both have the meaning to some degree. Are they interchangeable when they both have this meaning in spoken English?

Answer (score 4):

***Sort of*** (or ***kind of***)  come from the notion *type of* - like an apple is a *sort of fruit*, a cauliflower is a *kind of vegetable*.

The terms *sort of*, and *kind of* are applied metaphorically to lots of abstract ideas, as well as to objects.

"I'm *kind of* thinking she may win", means that the possibility of her winning is the type of sentiment you have on the matter.

Equally "I'm *sort of* wondering if there is any point in going to see him - he may be out".

**So *sort of* and *kind of* do boil down to the same thing as "a little", in a metaphorical sense**. But the terms are thoroughly idiomatic, when used in this way.

Comment: In my usage, "sort of worried" would be a shade lesser than "a little worried". I don't know how universal that is.

Comment: @ReedWade Yes. "Sort of worried" means perhaps, not exactly worried, but worried in some sense that is close to being worried. But if you are a "little worried", you are definitely worried, but in a small way. I'm not sure how clear that is! But certainly the second sounds more worried than the first!